# the icon calendar is incorrectly positioned on the field

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

For my field `validity`, I would like to create a calendar field:

[image]

my code is the following:

```
<div class="col-12 col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="validity">Validaty</label>
            <input id="validity" name="validity" type="text" class="form-control"
                [(ngModel)]="order.validity"
                style="background-color: white; max-width: 300px;width: 100%;"
                placeholder="Validity" autofocus>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to base myself on these two fields:

[image]

I have this code:

```
<div class="form-group row">
 <label for="picker2" class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-form-label">{{'startDate | t }}</label>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
       <div class="input-group" style="background-color: white; max-width: 300px;">
         <input id="picker2" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp2"
            ngbDatepicker #dp2="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="search.enddate">
               <div class="input-group-append" (click)="dp2.toggle()">
                     <div class="input-group-text">
                         <i class="icon-regular i-Calendar-4"></i>
                      </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to adapt the code except that, the icon is incorrectly positioned on the field.
I don't understand where is the problem?

```
<div class="col-12 col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="validity">{{'3735' | t}}</label>
         <input id="validity" name="validity"  class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp2"
            ngbDatepicker #dp2="ngbDatepicker"
            [(ngModel)]="order.validity "
            style="background-color: white; max-width: 300px;width: 100%;"
            placeholder="Validity" autofocus>

            <div class="input-group-append" (click)="dp2.toggle()">
                 <div class="input-group-text">
                     <i class="icon-regular i-Calendar-4"></i>
                  </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove `max-width: 300px;width: 100%;` css from the input and move input and label inside  `<div  class="input-group">`

Check if this resolves your issue.

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="validity">Stop</label>        
           <input id="validity" name="validity" type="text" class="form-control" style="background-color: white;" placeholder="STOP" autofocus>
        </div>            
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="validity">{{'3735' | t}}</label>
        <div  class="input-group">
         <input id="validity" name="validity"  class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp2"
            ngbDatepicker #dp2="ngbDatepicker"
            [(ngModel)]="order.validity "
            style="background-color: white;"
            placeholder="Validity" autofocus>

            <div class="input-group-append" (click)="dp2.toggle()">
                 <div class="input-group-text">
                     <i class="icon-regular i-Calendar-4"></i>
                  </div>
            </div>
           </div>
    </div>
</body>
```